# Sum up a row in excel using vb.net

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet.  I have summed up the columns, but now I need to sum up the individual totals across the row for a Grand total.  colums are P, Q, R, S, T.  Since there will always be a different number of rows for each worksheet I have gotten the last row of the data and I am adding 2 rows to it so that the total will be two rows down from the data.  I am putting the grand total in column B on the same row as the individual totals.   This is what I have at the moment.  Any help would be appreicated.

```
Dim r As Integer
r = lastRow + 2
orange = oSheet.Range("B" & r)
orange.Select()
oSheet.Cells(r, "B").Formula = _
           "=SUM(P:" & r + "Q:" & r + "R:" & r + "S:" & r + "T:" & r & ")"
```

I am getting this error:  "Conversion from string "Q:" to type 'Double' is not valid.".

Thanks!  Lora

Comment: You should use only & for concatenation: your code is trying to add `r` and `Q:` as though they are both numeric

Comment: BTW. title says "vb.net" while tag is "vba" - confusing

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to list each cell. The following should be enough:

```
oSheet.Cells(r, "B").Formula = "=SUM(P" & r.ToString() & ":T" & r.ToString() & ")"
```